# How to execute callable functions using AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

Callable functions in firebase can be executed as below:

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
```

I am wondering what is the equivalent of this in AngularFire2. I have scanned the documents and don't see any mention of this.

If there is no equivalent then how do i obtain a handle to underlying firebase object in AngularFire2 ?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you update your `angularfire2` version to `RC9` or higher - as this is when the [PR](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/1532/files) was merged.

```sh
npm install angularfire2@latest
```

Add `AngularFireFunctions` to your `providers` in your `app.module`.

```js
import { AngularFireFunctions } from 'angularfire2/functions';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AngularFireFunctions
  ],
});
```

Within your Component you can run `httpsCallable` function from `AngularFireFunctions`.

```js
constructor(
  private afFun: AngularFireFunctions,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // Angular Fire - Converts Promise to Observable
  this.afFun.httpsCallable('myFunction')({ text: 'Some Request Data' })
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(resp => {
      console.log({ resp });
    }, err => {
      console.error({ err });
    });

  // Convert back to Promise
  const respRef = await this.afFun.httpsCallable('myFunction')({ text: 'Some Request Data' })
    .toPromise();

  console.log({ respRef });
}
```

A [comment](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1789#issuecomment-417916872) in the AngularFire2 repo has asked why the response has been converted to an `Observable`. The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result) has the function returning a `Promise` - so be aware of the inconsistency - it could change in the future.