# Firebase functions in angular app not working

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an angular app with the following being imported:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/functions';
...
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
```

And when I access the firebase.functions() it shows in my intellisense.

```
var convertText = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('convertText');
```

The function convertText exists on my firebase account and works when accessed via http.

When the firebase.functions().httpsCallable() is called I get the follwoing error:

> TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function

Here are my libraries.

```
"@firebase/app": "^0.3.1",
"firebase": "^5.3.1",
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.9",
```

I followed the following tutorial:
[Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

I know firebase is working as I'm already using fireauth and firestore successfully.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: afaik, you have to run functions on the backend via nodejs, its also says that in the docs.

Comment: Is it `firebase.functions().httpsCallable` or `firebase.functions.httpsCallable`?  I thought the first one was for Firebase Admin, e.g. `admin.functions().`

Comment: It is for firebase.functions(). The link in my question provides a tutorial on how to access the function from within a (web) application.

Answer (score 1):

I've just answered this on another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456237/how-to-execute-callable-functions-using-angularfire2/52157401#52157401).

As a quick summary;

```js
constructor(
  private afFun: AngularFireFunctions
) { }

ngOnInit() { 
  this.afFun.httpsCallable('myFunction')({ text: 'Some Request Data' })
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(resp => {
      console.log({ resp });
    }, err => {
      console.error({ err });
    });
}
```